# Filtering tokens by frequency using filter_extremes in Gensim

Tags: python, dictionary, text-processing, gensim, corpus

I am trying to filter out tokens by their frequency using the filter_extremes function in Gensim (https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/corpora/dictionary.html). Specifically, I am interested in filtering out words that occur in "Less frequent than no_below documents" and "More frequent than no_above documents".

```
id2word_ = corpora.Dictionary(texts)
print(len(id2word_))
id2word_.filter_extremes(no_above = 0.600)
print(len(id2word_))
```

The first print statement gives 11918 and the second print statement gives 3567. However, if I do the following:

```
id2word_ = corpora.Dictionary(texts)
print(len(id2word_))
id2word_.filter_extremes(no_below = 0.599)
print(len(id2word_))
```

The first print statement gives 11918 (as expected) and the second gives 11406. Shouldn't `id2word_.filter_extremes(no_below = 0.599)` and `id2word_.filter_extremes(no_above = 0.600)` add up to the number of total words? However, 11406 +  3567 > 11918, so how come this sum exceeds the number of words in the corpus? That does not make sense since the filters should cover non-overlapping words, based off the explanation in the documentation.

If you have any ideas, I would really appreciate your input! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

According to the definition:

```
no_below (int, optional) – Keep tokens which are contained in at least no_below 
documents.

no_above (float, optional) – Keep tokens which are contained in no more than 
no_above documents (fraction of total corpus size, not an absolute number).
```

no_below is an int that represents a threshold filtering out number of occurrence of the tokens among documents above certain number. e.g. use no_below to filter out words appearing less than 10 times.

On the contrary, no_above is not a int but a float that represents faction of total corpus size. e.g. use no_above to filter out words appearing in more than 10% of all documents.

It's a little odd that no_below and no_above do not represent the same unit and therefore the confusion.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Is there any specific way or logic to set the best values for no_below and no_above

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the filter_extremes in Gensim, the units for "no_above" and "no_below" parameters are actually DIFFERENT. This is a bit odd, to be honest.

For "no_above", you want to put a number between 0 and 1 there (float). It should be a percentage that represents the portion of a word in total corpus size.

For "no_below", you want to have a integer. It should be the number of times when a word shows in corpus. It is a threshold.

Hope it clarifies your question.

Answer (score 2):

I write this as an extension to other users' answers. Yes, the two parameters are different and control different kinds of token frequencies. In addition notice the following error: filter_extremes assigns default values to no_above and no_below, so if you write:

```
id2word_.filter_extremes(no_below = 0.599)
```

it is effectively

```
id2word_.filter_extremes(no_below = 0.599, no_above=0.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

hope you had found the answer to your reply. I have been dabbling with the gensim library and found out that these two parameters 'no_below' and 'no_above' are probably best used together. The *no_below* as TS said is straightforward and returns token if frequency is *not less than* the parameter.

Some code samples, I am not sure if there are best practices but I usually tinker with the *no_above* starting from 1 (or 100% of the corpus) which makes the filtering exclusive of the whole corpus.

```
# filter if frequency not less than 2
# and tokens contained not more than 90% of corpus
dictionary.filter_extremes(no_below=2, no_above=0.9) 
print(len(dictionary))

# filter if frequency not less than 3 
# and tokens contained not more than 100% of corpus
dictionary.filter_extremes(no_below=3, no_above=1) 
print(len(dictionary))
```

In general, start with *no_above* corpus 100%, from there make adjustments.

Comment: Another idea is to save the dictionary result as .txt using the save() function. It will be in a good clean format to load as dataframe / table. It could be another way to manipulate and present your results.

Comment: *code snippet for above.
dictionary.save_as_text("dict_text.txt")

data = pd.read_csv('dict_text.txt', sep="\t", header=None)
data.columns = ["token_id", "token_name", "token_frequency"]

data.head()